# How do I find the optimal values for $\beta$ and $\beta_0$ for sparse linear regression model? Where does the mean of $\lambda$ come into account?

Tags: optimization, lasso, elastic-net, convex

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

Consider the sparse linear regression model:
$\min_{\beta_{0},\beta} \left \{ \frac{1}{2}\left \| \beta _{0}e + X\beta -y \right \|^{2} +\lambda\left \| \beta\right \|_{1}+\frac{\mu}{2}\left \| \beta  \right \|^2\right \}$,
where $\mu \ge 0$ and $\lambda > 0$ are the parameters, and $e$ is the all-ones vector.
Let $\bar{\lambda} = \left \| X^{^{T}} \left ( \frac{e^{T}y}{n}e-y \right )\right \|_{\infty}$ Show that $\left ( e^{T}y/n,0 \right )$ is an optimal solution of the model for any $\lambda \geq \bar{\lambda}$

Comment: It should be "$\lambda \geq \bar\lambda$", not vice versa. And here $\bar\lambda$ is the value you've defined, not the mean.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Also, I thought the line above lambda denotes the mean?

Comment: Symbols mean whatever you define them to be.  $\bar \lambda$ is explicitly defined after the word "Let."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses the notion of subgradients (see e.g. [these notes [PDF]](https://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_notes.pdf)).

The subgradient is
$$\begin{bmatrix}e & X \end{bmatrix}^\top (\beta_0 e + X \beta - y) + \lambda \partial(\|\beta\|_1) + \mu \beta. \tag{$*$}$$
where $\partial(\|\beta\|_1)$ is the set of vectors $(v_0, v)$ satisfying $v_0=0$ and $v_i \in \begin{cases} \{1\} & \beta_i > 0 \\ \{-1\} & \beta_i < 0 \\ [-1, 1] & \beta_i = 0 \end{cases}$ for $i \ne 0$. The above set ($*$) is this set $\partial(\|\beta\|_1)$ scaled by $\lambda$ and shifted by
$\begin{bmatrix}e & X \end{bmatrix}^\top (\beta_0 e + X \beta - y) + \mu \beta$.

A $\beta$ is optimal if $0$ lies in the above set ($*$).

---

When $\beta_0=e^\top y / n$ and $\beta = 0$, the above set ($*$) becomes

$$\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}e & X \end{bmatrix}^\top \left(\frac{e^\top y}{n} e - y\right) + \lambda (\{0\} \times [-1, 1] \times \cdots \times [-1, 1])
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ X^\top \left(\frac{e^\top y}{n} - y\right)\end{bmatrix} + \lambda (\{0\} \times [-1, 1] \times \cdots \times [-1, 1]).
\end{align}$$
where we have used the fact $e^\top e=n$.
For $0$ to lie in this set is the same as asking that every element of $X^\top \left(\frac{e^\top y}{n} - y\right)$ lies in $[-\lambda, \lambda]$. This is precisely the given condition involving $\bar{\lambda}$.

Comment: How do you get the subgradient of $\frac{1}{2}\left \| \beta _{0}e + X\beta -y \right \|^{2}$ to be $\left [ e,X \right ]^{T} \left ( \beta_0e + X\beta -y \right )$. I understand how the L1 norm subgradient is determined

Comment: @JeromyTrujillo If you are familiar with how the gradient of $\frac{1}{2} \|A \gamma - y\|^2$ w.r.t. $\gamma$ is $A^\top (A\gamma - y)$, then just note that $\beta_0 e + X \beta = \begin{bmatrix} e & X \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}$ and think of this as $A \gamma$.